# Heroku Toolbelt is currently updating issue

Tags: heroku-toolbelt

My Heroku Toolbelt is stuck updating.
When I run heroku in a console it says

**Heroku  Toolbelt is currently updating.**

I have tried to uninstall and re-install but still the same issue.

I also tried to remove it with revo uninstaller.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of completely uninstalling and reinstalling, I deleted a file called "updating" in "C:\Users\Profile-name\.heroku" and it started responding to commands again

Comment: As of 13th of May 2016, I had to delete `~/.heroku/autoupdate.last` in order to unlock the Heroku Toolbelt.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with the older buggy Heroku toolbelt version. Except my heroku commands were not running from local but from [Semaphore](https://semaphoreapp.com/) as a sequence of deploy steps.

Just running a update command first thing seems to solve the issue. Of this helps with your local toolbelt as well.

```
heroku update
```

Answer (score 1):

The 5 minute update by heroku can be bypassed by removing the background_update! line from updater.rb or updating the toolbelt to version 3.15.2. That version will only lock if there really is an update instead of every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Toolbelt.

Manually delete

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku
- C:\Users\Profile-name\ .heroku

Re-install toolbelt.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 0.3.15 of heroku toolbelt, heroku toolbelt will fail if an autoupdate is already in progress. Heroku toolbelt will check every 5 minutes for an update, so back-to-back heroku commands will fail unless another single heroku command has been run within the last 5 minutes.  This behavior was introduced by this commit:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku/commit/023c84d15cde5958631b240eeaadec01a3b49031

I noticed this because it breaks heroku_san which typically makes multiple heroku commands back-to-back.  Unfortunately, I don't see a workaround.  It would help toolbelt could provide some sort of option to disable autoupdate or increase the time period for checks.